# if string is empty statement and /user doesnt exist VB.net

Tags: vb.net, authentication

I keep being terminated on the program after i put an if string is empty statement and /user doesnt exist. I wanted to loop back and exit the msgbox inorder to fillout the fields or re-enter credentials yet i get terminated after it loop.

The sql is working and can sift through my database for existing accounts and able to go to the another form that I redirected as administrator
here is my code

I NEED to go back to the previous form inorder to fill out the form and enter...
`

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim user As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim pword As String = TextBox2.Text


        ConnectToDB()

        sql = "select * from rfidmaintest.administrator where username ='" & user & "' And pword = '" & pword & "'"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If user & pword = String.Empty Then
            MsgBox("EMPTY FIELDS")

        Else
            If dr.HasRows Then
                Me.Hide()
                admin.ShowDialog()

            Else
                MsgBox("User doesn't exist")
                TextBox1.Clear()
                TextBox2.Clear()

            End If
        End If


        cmd = Nothing
        dr.Close()
        cn.Close()

        Me.Hide()

    End Sub
```

i could reloop and fillout the fields that i need

Comment: Have you used your debugger? If not, why not?

Comment: What's the point of checking whether the credentials have been provided after you've already used them? This is an example of writing code without a clear idea of what that code has to do. If you already understood the steps then you would not write code out of order like that.

Comment: Also, is this really what you want: `If user & pword = String.Empty Then`? That's only going to determine whether both are empty, not whether one or the other is empty. Surely you need to check each one individually.

Comment: @jmcilhinney mr. im sorry if but i just started to code sometimes ago. Indeed i need to check one individually however i wanted to fix the termination problem first before i finished the block of code for checking fields individually

Comment: @Dai im sorry i hvae used it however it doenst give me the idea where i was wrong

Comment: haven't fix it yet how do i fix this

Comment: Thought about using a loop?  Perhaps a While Loop

Comment: Mr @Hursey thank you for commenting. I have fix the problem. I indeed put an me.close() statement outside the if statement and i thought that the if statement was the problem but the real one was the me.close(). Thank you!